# Changing the color of the footnote marker only at the bottom of the page

Tags: footnotes

Is it possible to change the color the footnote marker only at the bottom of the page?!.

I have this code in the premable

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[x11names, svgnames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
 colorlinks=true,
 linkcolor=DeepPink2,
 filecolor=magenta,
 urlcolor=Magenta3,
 citecolor=OrangeRed2
}
```

When I write something like:

```
This is footnote \footnote{blablabla}
```

Latex keep the color of the marker at the bottom of the page black and turns the color of the footnote number in the actual body of the page into the color declared by `\hypersetup` command.

I just need to change the color of the footnote marker at the bottom of the page into blue (say) but I want to keep the color of the footnote number in the body of the page as is.

Thanks in advance.